# Time-reversal operator for explicitly time-dependent systems

Tags: condensed-matter, polarization, time-reversal-symmetry

**I'll start with something more general and later go to my actual problem.**

The definition for the time reversal operator is

$$T=\underbrace{\exp\left(
  \frac{i\pi}{\hbar}S_y
 \right)}_{=:U}
 K$$
with the complex conjugation operator $K$ and the spin operator $S$. Let's restrict to bosons where $U=\mathbb{1}$. Then $T$ is just the complex conjugation. A tight-binding Hamiltonian
$$H_1(\vec{k}) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & e^{i \sum_a \vec{k} \vec{a}} \\\ e^{-i \sum_a \vec{k} \vec{a}} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
with sum over lattice vectors $\vec{a}$ therefore satisfies time-reversal symmetry, as
$$ TH_1(k)T^{-1} = H_1(-k).$$
However, I've only seen this equation for not explicitly time-dependent systems. If I look at a potential of the form
$$H_2(t)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(t) & 0 \\\ 0 & \cos(t)\end{pmatrix},$$
then it would satisfy
$$ TH_2(t)T^{-1} = H_2(t)= H_2(-t).$$
But if I instead pick
$$H_3(t)=\begin{pmatrix} \sin(t) & 0 \\\ 0 & \sin(t)\end{pmatrix},$$
I arrive at
$$ TH_3(t)T^{-1} = H_3(t)= -H_3(-t).$$
(Note the extra minus sign in front of the last term.)

This had me wondering. Is time-reversal (of time) only the operation
$$t\rightarrow -t$$
or is there a more general definition, e.g.
$$(t+t_0)\rightarrow(-t+t_0)$$

**In the following, I will give you my actual problem and my reason why I think we should be able to pick a $t_0$.**

The reason why I ask is that I included an electric field in my Hamiltonian. It is of the form

$$\vec{E}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} E_x\cos(\omega t) \\\ E_y\sin(\omega t) \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad\Rightarrow\quad\vec{A}(t) = \frac{1}{\omega}\begin{pmatrix} E_x\sin(\omega t) \\\ -E_y\cos(\omega t) \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

This leads to a Hamiltonian

$$H_4(\vec{k},t) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & e^{i \sum_a (\vec{k} \vec{a}+\frac{q}{\hbar}\vec{A}(t)\vec{a})} \\\ e^{-i \sum_a (\vec{k} \vec{a}+\frac{q}{\hbar}\vec{A}(t)\vec{a})} & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I know that circular polarisation breaks time-reversal symmetry whereas linear polarisation keeps it intact. So, based on that logic, we would need either $|E_x|$ or $|E_y|$ to be zero for time-reversal symmetry. But this condition turned out to be incorrect, at least as long as we don't consider a $t_0$. Instead, the only way to achieve
$$TH_4(\vec{k},t)T^{-1} = H_4(-\vec{k},-t)$$
is to have $E_x=0$ ($E_y$ seems to be completely irrelevant). This is because the sine (inside the vector potential $\vec{A}$) is antisymmetric under the operation $t\rightarrow-t$.

If we were able to pick a point $t_0$ in time to mirror our time at instead of only $t_0=0$, then we could choose $t_0=\frac{\pi}{2\omega}$ to arrive at the condition $E_y=0$ instead.

Maybe I'm overlooking something blatantly obvious, but I haven't found this problem of mine discussed anywhere in the literature I found.

Comment: Based on the discussion around equation (3) in the following source: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.96.155118 it seems that my assumption is correct and one needs to define a point around which TR symmetry applies its reversal.

Comment: If we translated all of this from time reversal to parity, which is nominally a very similar symmetry, I don't think these statements would be surprising. Namely, if you had a spatially varying potential that happened to have a reflection symmetry about a point, then the system would only be parity symmetric for reflections through that special point.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I think that earlier it was more confusing than it should be, since I had made a mistake (see edit history). Nonetheless, most sources I originally found only used the 0 as reference, and some colleagues actually told me I was just wrong for trying to mirror the time axis around another point than 0. So I was doubting myself.

Comment: Reflecting around a point other than 0 does admittedly feel wrong somehow! I get why this situation is confusing, it didn't make sense to me until I made an analogy with spatial reflections.